# Is it possible in Sailsjs to build more complex models

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I would like to have arrays or collections in my model, is this yet possible with waterline (mongoDB)? are there any alternatives around?

example:

```
{
   name: Bundle,
   col1 : {
      name : anOtherModel,
      subCol: {
         text: aString,
         ...
      }
   },
   col2 : {
      name : anOtherModel,
      subCol: {
         text: aString,
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

to:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes : {

        name : {
            type : 'STRING',
            required : true
        },
        basicModules: {
            type : 'ARRAY', // or 'COLLECTION'
            required : false
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find answer?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I think this is yet not possible!

Comment: Sails supports arrays in models after v0.9.x http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is still an issue, but the trick is to neither POST as "form-data" nor "x-www-url-encoded". You have to POST the "raw" content:

Assume the situation:
`http://www.example.com/mymodel`

---

### form-data

Your Header may look like this:

```
POST /mymodel/create HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="basicModules"

[1,2,3,4]
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

the result is that a string `"[1,2,3,4]"` gets (type-)validated, which fails

---

### x-www-url-encoded

In this case the Header is something like this:

```
POST /mymodel/create HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

basicModules=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D
```

which has exactly the same result as form-data. validation fails because of `basicModules` being the string `"[1,2,3,4]"`

---

### raw

to make it work your Header has to look like this:

```
POST /mymodel/create HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"basicModules":[1,2,3,4]}
```

which results in just exactly what you want, and type validation works.

---

so in the end, you can fill the most complex models that way in JSON. e.g.

```
POST /mymodel/create HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"user": {
         "name": {
           "first":"John",
           "last":"Doe"
         },
         "age":25,
         "pets":[{
           "name":"Garfield",
           "type":"cat"
         },
         {
           "name":"Rudolph",
           "type":"reindeer"
         }]
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for model associations, it's not there yet (look at [this issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/124) for proposed implementations) if you'd just like to have arrays of data stored in DB, you can have arrays as attribute (see [the doc](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models) for reference on that). I haven't tested it but I guess it will serialize the array prior to saving it in the DB if it doesn't have a matching structure.